# passing special characters as web parameters

Tags: java, angular, web-services, http-post, url-parameters

### UPDATE:

I defined the web parameter as const map = new Map(); and I put values inside with  map.set(metaById[i].id, metadatoForm[i]);

On the Angular side (trough browser console) I can see the item is passed correctly, but on the Java side I receive a strange object, it hasn't the correct size and it is empty (it has also empty keyset)

```
 @RequestParam Map<Integer,String> mapQuery) {
 ...
 System.out.println(mapQuery.size()); // always 1 even if hte map has more elements
 System.out.println(mapQuery.get(3)); // null
```

### OLD POST

here is my situation:

In my web application, written with Angular 4, I call web services and pass this web param

```
const param = 'map=' + map;
```

this map is not a real map, but an Array with this structure:

```
map=1:RUFUS,2:QUATTRO,3:21/01/01   .... and so on
```

On the web service I parse this web parameter and create a java Map with that content.

The problem is when inside the web parameter there are one of this symbols, "+" 
 "," and "%". I cannot filter them (the user can type them) and I don't know why on the java side the plus is seen as an empty char (""), the , is seen as array separator (so it returns error when I split the web parameter to parse it) and the % is seen as invalid web escape charatcter.

I thought about 2 solutions, but none of them worked for all the three symbols:

1) typescript encodeUrl or encodeUrlComponents functions

2) change the web parameter type, (how can I pass directly a map ??

Here is how i parse the http-request param:

```
Map<Integer, String> mappaQuery = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (String item : arrayQuery) {
    String split[] = item.split(":");
    mappaQuery.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), split[1]);
}
```

Thanks for your help. I don't know if what I typed is clear enough, please comment and I'll add the better I can, English is not my main language.

Comment: Is the user able to type the ':' character too? Can you provide us with an example request?

Comment: basically none inputs is forbidden, so user can type ":". But I don't kow why, I have no problems with that.

Comment: I've tried to pass a map on the angular side, instead of an Array. With that I should avoid the "," problem. But Now java doesn't know how to parse it.. look the edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work, even it is not the most elegant way. 
I had to accept this solution because of the particular situation I have in my applications module (Angular which cal a REST WS, and need to pass a map like element). If I'll find better solutions, I'll write theme here.

In the Typescrypt part I encoded the sent data, after searching and replacing "," chars. I used | instead of : as K/V separator in my array.

```
nome.trim().replace(',', '%2C');
...
array.push(this.metaById[i].id + '|' + encodeURIComponent(this.metadatoForm[i]));
```

On the java side the solution is not so elegant, but it covers all the possibilities:

```
Map<Integer, String> mappaQuery = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (String item : arrayQuery) {
        String split[] = item.split("\\|");
        if (split.length >= 2) {
            if (item.contains("%2C")) {
                mappaQuery.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), URLDecoder.decode(split[1], "UTF-8"));
            } else {
                mappaQuery.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), split[1]);
            }
        } else if (split.length == 1) {
            mappaQuery.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), "|");
        }
    }
```

With that I have no more problems passing , : % + and | in the search. Note I do not decode the URI Component unless I receive an encoded ,

Hope this helps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Angular app:

```
class CustomEncodingCodec implements HttpParameterCodec {
  private customEncoding(v: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(v)
      .replace(/%3A/gi, ':')
      .replace(/%24/gi, '$')
      .replace(/%2C/gi, ',')
      .replace(/%3B/gi, ';')
      .replace(/%3D/gi, '=')
      .replace(/%3F/gi, '?')
      .replace(/%2F/gi, '/'); 
  }

  encodeKey(k: string): string { return this.customEncoding(k); }
  encodeValue(v: string): string { return this.customEncoding(v); }
  decodeKey(k: string): string { return decodeURIComponent(k); }
  decodeValue(v: string) { return decodeURIComponent(v); }
}

let httpParams = new HttpParams( { fromString: '', encoder: new CustomEncodingCodec() } );
```

Then pass your parameters from the map to the httpParams.

More info: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpUrlEncodingCodec

Hope it will help.

Comment: How will I parse on the java side ? how do I split the sent array ? Probably it will not resolve the "," problem If I decode before the split . but I'm trying

Comment: On the Java side, you could try URLDecoder.decode("your_url_here", "UTF-8") [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).
Then split the returned string as you wish.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but I'm bit confused. Why should I replace /%2C/gi with "," if the colon character is the one I don't want to receive directly ? And why do you call new CustomEncodingCodec() ?? 
can you please post a working plunker ?

Comment: Here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/a2DC6DbOO2LFbCD9mg1u?p=info
But as I can see, ',' characters aren't escaped. Have you been able to get it to work?